# MYSql select with exclusions (problems with not in and not like)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all column names, excluding those that contain the string "id". Such as id, project_id, client_id. I used NOT LIKE and NOT IN, but for some reason I am still getting all columns. Does it have something to do with using information_schema, any ideas?

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE 
`COLUMN_NAME` NOT IN('id', 'project_id')
AND `TABLE_SCHEMA`= 'projects' AND `TABLE_NAME`='building' OR 
TABLE_NAME = 'characteristics'
```

Also

```
   Select .. WHERE COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%id%' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join the column  on the column with id and check for column_name null

```
  SELECT TABLE_NAME, `COLUMN_NAME` 
  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`  T1
  left join (

    select TABLE_NAME.`COLUMN_NAME` 
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `COLUMN_NAME` like '%id%'


  ) T2 on T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME AND T1.COLUMN_NAME = T2.COLUMN_NAME 
  WHERE T2.COLUMN_NAME is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good case for using regular expressions to match column names ending, rather than containing, 'id'.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'projects' 
AND TABLE_NAME IN ('building', 'characteristics', 'client', 'contact', 'occupancy_types', 'project', 'project_team', 'sf330', 'stone_team', 'threats') 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT REGEXP 'id$';
```